# Moving 3D charracter - I don't want any physics, expected of collisions, and gravity

Tags: libgdx, bullet

I am working on a game. I constructed my player as here: (I am using a gravity on my world)

```java
private ArrayMap<String, GameObject.Constructor> constructors = new ArrayMap<String, GameObject.Constructor>(String.class, GameObject.Constructor.class);

private ArrayList<GameObject> instances = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

assets.load("hand.obj", Model.class);
...
    model = assets.get("hand.obj", Model.class);
        constructors.put("hand", new GameObject.Constructor(model, new btBoxShape(new Vector3(2.5f, 7.5f, 2.5f)), 1f));
...
    hand = constructors.get("hand").construct(); // that construct method returns me model, shape and constructions.. the GameObject extends ModelInstance, so i can use it like a modelinstance
        hand.transform.setToTranslation(x, y, z);
        hand.body.proceedToTransform(hand.transform);
        hand.body.setUserValue(instances.size());
        hand.body.setCollisionFlags(hand.body.getCollisionFlags()| btCollisionObject.CollisionFlags.CF_CUSTOM_MATERIAL_CALLBACK);
           world.addRigidBody(hand.body);
           hand.body.setContactCallbackFlag(OBJECT_FLAG);
           hand.body.setContactCallbackFilter(OBJECT_FLAG);
```

Then, in render method I am moving it:

```java
if (!hand.body.isActive()) hand.body.activate();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)){
        hand.body.translate(new Vector3(0,0,-1));
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S))    {
            hand.body.translate(new Vector3(0,0,+1));
        }
```

That's nice! The moving now works good, when I am moving at the flat ground. Whenever there is an object before me, it is not as expected. Because my player shape is biger than
 object shape (which is 2.5f, 2.5f, 2.5f), it kind of falls on it. So I would like to set the rotation to be still the same, so the object will not be rotating (so it will not "fall" on the object before). And so I tried to do it, and I failed. Because there are functions like rotate, and I want to something like setRotation
 . And so, there is a setToRotation, but you can not pass there a Quaternion.

I need help. I tried to use a btKinematicCharacterController but it was bad. The ghostObject every time falled through object, but the objects got a collision from him.

and so I want to create a player movment, like in games like Wow, minecraft, and so on.

---

I looked at the `btKinematicCharacterController` again. The reason why my ghostobject falled through the ground was. Generally, I don't know the reason: D probably I was using another broadphase for ghost, that for world. This line fixes it: `characterController.setUseGhostSweepTest(false);`
and I am getting another problem, when I am walking on my ground (a lot of objects), the character is getting to lesser Y position. I don't know why.
Here is my construction:

```java
    btPairCachingGhostObject ghostObject;
    btConvexShape ghostShape;
    btKinematicCharacterController characterController;
    Vector3 characterDirection = new Vector3();
    Vector3 walkDirection = new Vector3();
...

       ghostObject = new btPairCachingGhostObject();
               ghostObject.setWorldTransform(hand.transform);
               ghostShape = new btCapsuleShape(5f, 0.5f);
               ghostObject.setCollisionShape(ghostShape);
               ghostObject.setCollisionFlags(btCollisionObject.CollisionFlags.CF_CHARACTER_OBJECT);
               characterController = new btKinematicCharacterController(ghostObject, ghostShape, .00001f);
               // And add it to the physics world
               characterController.setUseGhostSweepTest(false);
               world.addCollisionObject(ghostObject,
               (short)btBroadphaseProxy.CollisionFilterGroups.CharacterFilter,
               (short)(btBroadphaseProxy.CollisionFilterGroups.StaticFilter | btBroadphaseProxy.CollisionFilterGroups.DefaultFilter));
               world.addAction(characterController);
... (in render - moving)
    if (!load)
        {
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
                hand.transform.rotate(0, 1, 0, 5f);
                ghostObject.setWorldTransform(hand.transform);
                }
                if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
                    hand.transform.rotate(0, 1, 0, -5f);
                ghostObject.setWorldTransform(hand.transform);
                }
                // Fetch which direction the character is facing now
                characterDirection.set(-1,0,0).rot(hand.transform).nor();
                // Set the walking direction accordingly (either forward or backward)
                walkDirection.set(0,0,0);
                if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP))
                walkDirection.add(characterDirection);
                if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN))
                walkDirection.add(-characterDirection.x, -characterDirection.y, -characterDirection.z);
                walkDirection.scl(4f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                // And update the character controller
                characterController.setWalkDirection(walkDirection);
                // And fetch the new transformation of the character (this will make the model be rendered correctly)
        }
        world.stepSimulation(delta, 5, 1f/60f);
        if (!load)
        ghostObject.getWorldTransform(hand.transform);
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up the debugDrawer, so i was able to see the shapes of the bullet objects.. and my problem was that: the ghostObject(charController) was pushing my objects down.. Although my objects were static. So i set the mass of the objects to 0 and problem is fixed.  But I still dont know, how it could push static objects. But i dont care. :)

EDIT: i will accept this answer in 2 hours, because now i cant.